# Google Maps: Shade city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, google-visualization

I searched a lot, but I could not find how to shade city area on google maps. This can be done using Google Charts but it is not interactive. I want it to be exactly like google maps but with borders.
E.g Search Dallas on Google Maps and see it draws boundries. I want exactly like this to show on my website. I want to show multiple city borders in same map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps API doesn't provide this feature. So, if you want to highlight regions you have to create custom overlays based on the lat/long of the borders of the state.

Once you have the lat/long of the borders you have to draw polygons yourself.

For example:

```
// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
    var washingtonShapeCoords = [new google.maps.LatLng(38.8921, -76.9112),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(38.7991, -77.0320),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(38.9402, -77.1144),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(38.9968, -77.0430),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(38.8996, -76.9167),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(33.7243, -74.8843),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(33.7243, -72.6870),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(32.3243, -72.6870),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(32.3985, -76.7300),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(33.7152, -76.6957),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(33.7243, -74.9489),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(38.8921, -76.9112)];

// Construct the polygon.
  washingtonPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: washingtonShapeCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  washingtonPolygon.setMap(map);
```